# How to pass string of comma-separated numbers to stored procedure in condition for numeric field?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure like below where multiple employee IDs will be passed as comma-separated value (multiple IDs). It is throwing error as "ORA-01722: invalid number". I know it's because of passing varchar2 variable for the numeric ID column. But is there any way we can achieve this simply?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  Fetch_Emp_Name(Emp_id in varchar2)
IS

BEGIN

select Name from EMP where id in (emp_id);

END;
```

Comment: If you're passing multiple IDs then you're expecting it to find multiple names, right? What will your procedure do with those?

Comment: Including sample data and a sample call (with multiple values) and the expected result would be helpful. Also, where is the string of values coming from - can that be changed to a collection of values instead, on the callers side?

Comment: @Prabakaran,  then you are saying that so many emp_ids might be passed in the input parameter split by comma ??

Comment: Yes I am expecting multiple names as output. Using the out put names i will do insert in another table. i can call as only string variable. And the sample will be like Exec Fetch_Emp_Name('1,2,3');

Comment: @Prabakaran, I post a new answer where I handled different IDs into the same p_empid variable. Please, be free to comment anything in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Fetch_Emp_Name(emp_id in varchar2) IS
v_result varchar2;
begin
    execute immediate
        'select Name from EMP where id in (' || 'emp_id' || ')'
    into
        v_result;             
end;
```

Also you can use package [dbms_sql](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm) for dynamic sql.

**Update**

Another approach. I think may be better.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Fetch_Emp_Name(emp_id in varchar2) IS
v_result varchar2;
begin
    select 
        Name 
    from 
        EMP 
    where 
        id in
            (
                select 
                    to_number(regexp_substr(emp_id, '[^,]+', 1, level)) 
                from 
                    dual
                connect by regexp_substr(emp_id, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null

            );
exception
    when no_data_found then
        -- error1;
    when too_many_rows then
        -- error2;                
end;
```

Comment: If there are multiple IDs then it will (presumably) find multiple names; which will get a too-many-rows error when you try to put them all into the scalar `v_result` string.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes it's right. You need handle exceptions too. I just told about approach for getting desired result.

Comment: @AntonTokmakov - it's not about handing the exception if that happens; the question says the string has multiple IDs, so you'd *expect* it to find multiple rows in the table, wouldn't you?

Comment: sql injection. Antoshka, you should use bind variable. No need dbms_sql.

Comment: @AlexPoole I added another answer, may be better.

Comment: @akk0rd87 It was just simple example, that resolves user's question.

Comment: Yes. The second is much better. But I prefer '\d+' instead of '[^,]+'. What is the weather in Krasnodar?

Comment: @akk0rd87 Hot, what is your name?)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for before, I did not get the question in the right way. If you get a lot of IDs as different parameters, you could retrieve the list of names as an string split by comma as well. I put this code where I handled by `regexp_substr` the name of different emp_ids you might enter in the input parameter.

Example ( I am assuming that the IDs are split by comma )

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Fetch_Emp_Name(p_empid in varchar2) IS
    v_result varchar2(4000);
    v_append emp.name%type;
    v_emp    emp.emp_id%type;
    counter  pls_integer;
    i pls_integer;
    begin
       -- loop over the ids 
       counter := REGEXP_COUNT(p_empid ,'[,]') ;
       --dbms_output.put_line(p_empid);
       if counter > 0
       then 
           i := 0;
           for r in ( SELECT to_number(regexp_substr(p_empid,'[^,]+',1,level)) as mycol FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(p_empid ,'[,]')+1 )
           loop
               --dbms_output.put_line(r.mycol);
               v_emp := r.mycol ;
               select name into v_append from emp where emp_id = v_emp; 
               if i < 1 
               then 
                v_result := v_append ;
               else 
                v_result := v_result ||','|| v_append ;
               end if;
               i := i + 1;             
           end loop;
       else 
           v_emp := to_number(p_empid);
           select name into v_result from emp where emp_id = v_emp; 
       end if;
       dbms_output.put_line(v_result);
       exception 
       when no_data_found 
       then 
           raise_application_error(-20001,'Not Employee found for '||v_emp||' ');
       when too_many_rows 
       then 
           raise_application_error(-20002,'Too many employees for id '||v_emp||' ');
    end;
```

Test

```
SQL> create table emp ( emp_id number, name varchar2(2) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into emp values ( 1 , 'AA' );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into emp values ( 2 , 'BB' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

SQL> insert into emp values ( 3 , 'CC' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL>  select * from emp ;

    EMP_ID NA
---------- --
         1 AA
         2 BB
         3 CC

SQL>  exec Fetch_Emp_Name('1') ;
AA

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec Fetch_Emp_Name('1,2,3') ;
AA,BB,CC

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```